# How to replace following OBJECT(o) with space from payload using expression component in Mule?

Tags: regex, mulesoft

How to replace following OBJECT(o) with space from payload using expression component in Mule? I have tried to use the following expression but it does not work.

`<expression-transformer expression="#[payload.replaceAll('OBJECT(o)', ' ')]" doc:name="Expression"/>`

Comment: That will work if your payload is a String that contains OBJECT(o). Can you verify what your payload is before that processor?

Comment: Yes the payload is a string. I am reading a file and converted the payload to string using file to string component. I have logged the payload before and after the expression component but no change in payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `replace` (see [Mulesoft docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dw-core-functions-replace)). Note the escape character ('\') before the internal parentheses.

```
payload replace /(OBJECT\(o\))/ with " "
```